# Assign two dimensional array to panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to explode the two dimensional array into 1 dimensional array and assign it to the panda data frame. Need help on this

```
This is my panda data frame. 

 Id       Dept            Date

100    Healthcare        2007-01-03
100    Healthcare        2007-01-10
100    Healthcare        2007-01-17

Two dimensional array looks like

array([[10, 20, 30],
       [40, 50, 60],
       [70, 80, 90]])
```

The output to be.

```
 Id       Dept            Date                vect

100    Healthcare        2007-01-03          [10, 20, 30]
100    Healthcare        2007-01-10          [40, 50, 60]
100    Healthcare        2007-01-17          [70, 80, 90]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.   Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions.   In your case, please show what you've tried so far, and explain why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by convert the `array` to `list` by using `tolist`

```
df['vect']=ary.tolist()
df
Out[281]: 
    Id        Dept        Date          vect
0  100  Healthcare  2007-01-03  [10, 20, 30]
1  100  Healthcare  2007-01-10  [40, 50, 60]
2  100  Healthcare  2007-01-17  [70, 80, 90]
```

Comment: Can't you just use the one statement: `df['vect']=ary.tolist()`?